# How can I get MoreUnit to debug tests rather than run them?

Tags: eclipse, junit, moreunit

I've just started using [MoreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/#home) and it seems quite handy. One thing that I am missing however is how to run tests using the debugger right away rather than just plain Run (using ^R).

It's not in the context menu and I have tried a few keyboard shortcut variations to no avail...

Comment: Usually in Eclipse, you can just click on the debug button after running the tests normally to debug them (the last run will have created a launch configuration that you can also access from the debug menus).

Comment: Thanks, that's true, but I want to run the debugger right away - not run then debug.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Eclipse, you can just click on the debug button after running the tests normally to debug them (the last run will have created a launch configuration that you can also access from the debug menus).

Other than that, you should find a "Run as MoreUnit test..." in both the "Run" and "Debug" menus (if not, file a feature request).

Lastly, you should be able to open the "Launch Configuration" wizard by selecting "Debug..." and there should be a folder for MoreUnit in the tree on the left. Above the tree is a "+" option to create entries in a folder.